# Adding time spent in different EU countries for PR as a dependent of EU Blue Card holder

Tags: blue-card

> With an EU Blue Card, it will be easier for you to get long-term residence status, as the rules for calculating the period of time necessary are more generous (you can add together periods of time spent in different EU countries, instead of the whole five years being in just one EU country).
>
> [https://immigration-portal.ec.europa.eu/blue-card/essential-information_en#:~:text=With%20a%20valid%20EU%20Blue,months%20(read%20more%20below)](https://immigration-portal.ec.europa.eu/blue-card/essential-information_en#:%7E:text=With%20a%20valid%20EU%20Blue,months%20(read%20more%20below)).

Does this also hold true if someone has a normal Temporary Residency Permit and is a dependent(spouse) of the EU Blue Card holder?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this also hold true if someone has a normal Temporary Residency Permit and is a dependent (spouse) of the EU Blue Card holder?

The directive doesn't suggest it would necessarily be the case. But family members also have some rights under directive 2003/109/EC so as soon as the Blue card holder becomes a long-term resident, their family is (somewhat) protected against any risk of expulsion as well. All this is contingent on maintaining the family link, other rules might apply if, e.g., the couple divorces. And the spouse doesn't gain any independent right to move or work in another EU country than the EU Blue card holder / permanent resident.